# Taking ownership of vector twice

Tags: rust

I am trying to figure out the best way to use two functions on the same vector?  I'm able to get both functions to do what I need them to do but as soon as I want to use them both on the same vector, I can't seem to make that compile "reasonably".  I imagine I can just stick a bunch of `mut`s and `&`s everywhere but that seems like a lot just to get two functions to run on the same vector as opposed to one.  Am I missing some best practice here that can make this simpler?

Current code that fails compilation with `` v is a `&` reference `` error:

```
fn main() {
    let vec = vec![1,2,1,4,5];
    println!("Mean: {}, Median: {}", mean(&vec), median(&vec))
}

fn mean(v: &Vec<i32>) -> i32 {
    v.iter().sum::<i32>() / v.len() as i32
}

fn median(v: &Vec<i32>) -> i32 {
    v.sort();
    let med_idx = v.len() / 2 as usize;
    v[med_idx]
}
```

Comment: " I imagine I can just stick a bunch of muts and &s everywhere but that seems like a lot just to get two functions to run on the same vector as opposed to one." Every value in rust has one owner. To give it to multiple functions, you have to specify a borrow (`&`), to give mutable access to a function, you have to specify it `&mut`.

Comment: There is no way around sticking a bunch of `mut`s and `&`s everywhere. `fn median(v: &mut Vec<i32>)` and `let mut vec` will solve your problem.

Comment: Ok thanks.  It's possible I'm just overconcerned with potential complexity down the road.  For this exercise, it doesn't matter so much.  Is it safe to assume that most Rust codebases have a lot of refs and mutable refs (a majority of arguments being that, really)?  Or am I fundamentally printing these two results a suboptimal way?

Comment: @SamDillard Yes, Rust uses refs extensively. Mutability is a little frowned upon in Rust, it bites a little of functional programming here. Other than (mutable) refs, you can only pass argument ownership (without any `&`), but it's less common than borrowing the value. I'd highly recommend going through The Rust Programming Language book, it reiterates on ownership multiple times from different angles.

Comment: @yeputons I'm half way through it!  Just working on exercises in parallel and I guess not fully grasping the convention yet.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do that. Rust requires you to think about ownership and constness very deeply. For example, your `median` function seems to sort vector internally: you should either allow it to modify the argument passed (`median(v: &mut Vec<i32>)` in the function definition and `&mut v` in the argument) or make a copy explicitly inside. However, if you allow mutating the vector, the original vector should be mutable itself (`let mut vec`). So, you can hack your way through like this:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut vec = vec![1,2,1,4,5];  // !
    println!("Mean: {}, Median: {}", mean(&vec), median(&mut vec))  // !
}

fn mean(v: &Vec<i32>) -> i32 {
    v.iter().sum::<i32>() / v.len() as i32
}

fn median(v: &mut Vec<i32>) -> i32 {  // !
    v.sort();
    let med_idx = v.len() / 2 as usize;
    v[med_idx]
}
```

However, making `median` modify the vector it analyzes seems very weird to me. I think it would be better to make an explicit copy and sorting it:

```rust
fn main() {
    let vec = vec![1,2,1,4,5];
    println!("Mean: {}, Median: {}", mean(&vec), median(&vec))
}

fn mean(v: &Vec<i32>) -> i32 {
    v.iter().sum::<i32>() / v.len() as i32
}

fn median(v: &Vec<i32>) -> i32 {  // !
    let v_sorted = v.sorted();  // creates a copy
    let med_idx = v.len() / 2 as usize;
    v[med_idx]
}
```

If you don't want the penalty, you can stick with the first solution and just create a copy on call site. This gives the most flexibility:

```rust
fn main() {
    let vec = vec![1,2,1,4,5];
    println!("Mean: {}, Median: {}", mean(&vec), median(&mut vec.clone()))  // !
}

fn mean(v: &Vec<i32>) -> i32 {
    v.iter().sum::<i32>() / v.len() as i32
}

fn median(v: &mut Vec<i32>) -> i32 {  // !
    v.sort();
    let med_idx = v.len() / 2 as usize;
    v[med_idx]
}
```

Comment: Great answer -- thank you!  You're right, it is weird to modify the original vector with `median()`.  I'm curious -- in Python there is a `sort()` and `sorted()` function, one modifies in place like this Rust `sort()` and the other returns a sort but doesn't mutate the original.  Is there a function that doesn't mutate the original in Rust or is making the explicit copy the only way (in a sense, doing that in two steps)?

Comment: @SamDillard It's a two step process because Rust cares deeply about excess copies and memory management, akin to C++. You cannot sort a vector without allocating at least some extra memory, so there is no `sorted()`. There may be some packages which provide such extra functionality, though.